# How to change QtCurve style/theme without KDE via config file editing?

Tags: window-manager, theme, qt, appearance, qt4

I have downloaded a QtCurve theme. I do not use KDE, I use a standalone WM (awesome). How do I change QtCurve style/theme via config file editing? Which config file contains this setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The qtcurve config file is ~/.config/qtcurve/stylerc.

You can copy the contents of your downloaded xxxx.qtcurve file into that file.

You can customise many aspetcs of your theme. To understand the functions of keys (activeTabAppearance, appearance, …) you can examine [this file.](https://quickgit.kde.org/?p=qtcurve.git&a=blob&h=81d693b31a67d5dcb7264a40cabee92f79003a5f&hb=a3fff13ed5a362064c7abee8485e224be945cdc6&f=qt5%2Fconfig%2Fqtcurveconfigbase.ui)

Yet I couldn't find a reference for values (darkinverted, origselected, …). You have to find by trial and error I guess. I've found many of them in this way. Yet I can't change the normal background colour, that is, the background colour of the main window of a file manager, for instance.

To be able to use qtcurve for all your qt5 apps you need to enter this line into your ~/.bashrc:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=qtcurve
```

**qt5ct way**

The easiest and better option is to use qt5ct which is a qt5-config tool like the old qt4-config (but a much better one). This utiliy allows you to change every aspect of your qt5 theme easily including widget style (qtcurve, fusion, kvantum…) icon theme, font etc.

**qt5ct now has colour presets as well.**

To use qt5ct you need to add this line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

**kvantum**

This is another option. You can choose kvantum in qt5ct or you can use just kvantum without qt5ct (though loosing the ability to set the font and icon theme). It has kvantummanager along with the main utility to choose and customize your kvantum theme (either a preset you can find in http://kde-look.org/ or your own creation). Some detailed aspects of your theme may be customised by editing your kvantum theme (pointed out in kvantummanager window). This utility doesn't have any KDE dependency. It can be built both for qt4 and qt5.

To be able to use this style (without qt5ct) you need to enter this line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum
```

**virtuality**

This is yet another option like kvantum, having its own customisation utility. It's been created by the bespin developer for qt5. Haven't tried this for some time.